Tao Analysis I Exercise 3.5.12(i) on Recursively Defined Functions
I am a self-teaching beginner and need some advice on my attempt to do part (1) of Exercise 3.5.12 from Tao's Analysis I 4th ed.
My question is specifically about the following steps in the proof:

The validity of choosing to define the function such that $a_N = a_M$ for $M < N$. I assume this is ok for proofs of existence.

The proof of uniqueness by induction. That is, showing the base case is unique. Showing the indicative step preserves uniqueness if the inductive hypothesis assumes it.



Exercise 3.5.12(i)

This exercise will establish a rigorous version of Proposition 2.1.16 that avoids circularity (in particular, avoiding the use of any object that required Proposition 2.1.16 to construct).
(i) Let $X$ be a set, let $f : \mathbb{N} \times X \to X$ be a function, and let $c$ be an element of $X$. Show that there exists a function $a : X \to X$ such that
$$a(0) = c$$
and
$$a(n++) = f(n, a(n)) \text{ for all } n \in \mathbb{N}$$
and furthermore that this function is unique. (Hint: first show inductively, by a modification of the proof of Lemma 3.5.11, that for every natural number $N \in \mathbb{N}$, there exists a unique function $a_N:\{n \in \mathbb{N}:n \leq N\} \to X$ such that $a_N(0)=c$ and $a_N(n++)= f(n,a_N(n))$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $n < N$.)

Note: I am aware other posts on this exercise exist but the solution discussion is too advanced for me. I believe there is value in a solution and discussion for a beginner that understands basic sets, functions and inductive proof. Also please don't simply point to a textbook proof - I want to learn by understanding what is wrong with my own proof. Thanks.

Solution
To show that for every natural number $N \in \mathbb{N}$ there exists a unique function $a_N$ as defined in the question, we will use induction on $N$.
Consider the statement $P(N):$ there is a unique function $a_N:\{n \in \mathbb{N}:n \leq N\} \to X$ which meets the two conditions:

$a_N(0)=c$
$a_N(n++)= f(n,a_N(n))$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $n < N$

Base case P(0): We can define a function $a_0 : \{0\} \to X$ where $a_0(0) = c$.
This meets the first condition by definition, and the second condition is vacuously true because there is no $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $n<N=0$.
This $a_0:\{0\}\to X$ is also unique. If there were another function $b_0:\{0\}\to X$ which met the same conditions, it would mean $b_0(0)=c$. Since they map every element of the domain, in this case $\{0\}$, to the same $c \in X$, the two functions are equal.
Inductive Hypothesis P(N): We will assume the function $a_N:\{0, \ldots, N\} \to X$ exists, meets the two conditions, and is unique.
Inductive Step P(N++): We need to show $a_{N+1}$ exists, meets the two conditions, and is unique. Let's define it as follows:
$$a_{N+1} : \{0, \ldots, N+1\} \to X \quad \text{ where } \quad \begin{cases}a_{N+1}(0) &= c \\ \\ a_{N+1}(n++) &= f(n, a_{N++}(n)) \\ & = f(n, a_{N}(n)) \end{cases}$$
where $n < N+1$.
By its definition it meets the first condition, $a_{N+1}(0)=c$. The second condition is met because we chose to define $a_{N}$ to equal $a_{N-1}$, which gives us $f(n, a_{N++}(n)) = f(n, a_{N}(n))$, which in turn means $a_{N+1}$ exists.
The inductive hypothesis tells us $a_N$ exists and is unique. This means $f(n, a_{N}(n))$ is unique because $f$ is a well-defined function. So if $f(n, a_{N}(n))$  exists and is unique, we have shown $a_{N+1}$ exists and is unique.
Thus, by induction, a unique $a_N$ exists for all $N \in \mathbb{N}$.
This means there exists a function $a : X \to X$ such that
$$a(0) = c$$
and
$$a(n++) = f(n, a(n)) \text{ for all } n \in \mathbb{N}$$
and furthermore that this function is unique. $\square$
